# Verb in position 1 (not in a question or imperativ)

Tags: sentence-structure

1. Machen wir das- answering "lets do it"
2. Kann ich auch das machen- answering that you also can do something
3. Habe ich das gemacht - answering that you have done something

I've seen and heard this many times. Is it considered slang?
Or there is a rule to when I can put the verb in 1st position?

Of course i know that in a question and imperativ it works that way, but i thought that beside these 2 options, verb in first position can never happen in Deutsch

Thanks

Comment: It was not a good idea to add _das_ at the end when you edited your question, because this changed the structure of the sentences and makes the current answer by _tofro_ obsolete.

Comment: I'm not sure he's correct. And regarding the edit, this is what i meant on the first place. If he's answer doesn't fit now that's because there maybe a better explanation

Comment: Many sentences that i know i heard are "Machen wir das" and "habe ich das gemacht". What the answer says is wrong, it means "we'll do it"(future) not "let us do it" (now)

Comment: My teacher and a lot others says there is no such thing as self imperative, you can't be part of the action so "machen wir das" is not imperative, it also means total different thing. And what about "ja, hab' ich das" that's clearly not imperative.

Comment: No they are not questions now...hab ich simply means, yea i have done something.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77322/discussion-between-tomas-and-bjorn-friedrich).

Comment: You seem angry, you can relax now. I can argue about the fact that this is not imperative because it is simply not... When other native speakers read this we'll see who's right. And how do u suggest that i am not native as well?

Comment: Hab ich das gemacht is an answer. Ja, hab ich das gemacht. Ofcourse it can be a question. But also native speakers answer that way. And because I am new here it doesn't mean i don't speak better than you

Comment: You are asking another question as before now, apparently because my answer didn't suit you. Note acting like that is considered rude - You are invalidating answers that took people effort to write.

Comment: I am closing this questions as unclear because a major edit by the OP lead to the unfortunate situation of two answers, both for one version of the question. This is discouraged as we want to see a best answer evolve from a single, answerable question. Please consider another edit to make clear what **exactly** was you issue, and where you need our help. Thank you.

Comment: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adhortativ

Answer (score 4):

## Note this answer is invalidated by an edit to the question

This is rather a *pronoun swallowed* by colloquialism than a *verb in first position*. Those sentences should, in proper form, rather be:

- > **Das** machen wir
- > **Das** kann ich auch
- > **Das** habe ich

This often happens if it is clear from the context what the sentence is actually referring to, similar to the English:

- > I'll do [that]
- > That'll do [the trick]

Comment: You sure about that? I saw some sentences as "Machen wir es"/"Machen wir das", so it means that the pronoun wasn't omitted

Comment: *Machen wir das* and *machen wir es* will only work as question or imperative. *Machen wir* is clearly neither. And yes, I am sure ;)

Comment: It doesn't work as imperative.. Imperative would be only when you ain't part of the action (mach du/macht sie/machen Sie), when it is wir (I am also part of the action), it will never be imperative.

Comment: There is an *imperative to self* in German that is expressed through the indicative: "Machen wir" is of that form - "In Zukunft machen wir solche Fehler aber nicht mehr"

Comment: @Tomas "Imperative would be only when you ain't part of the action." That's not right.

Comment: This is a first... Imperative to self would be C3 lvl hehe our teacher never said this exists.

Answer (score 2):

I refer to the question **after** the first major edit was done, where a *das* was added in each example at specific positions that made the sentence structures change and, therefore, the previous answer by @tofro obsolete. The current sentences are:

> 1. Machen wir *das*
> 2. Kann ich auch *das* machen
> 3. Habe ich *das* gemacht

You want to know why the verb is in the first position and not in the second one as you would expect in case of declarative statements.

The answer is: none of the examples is, now that the edit is done, a proper declarative statement in German. And since the punctuation marks are missing, we have to interpret what else they can be.

There are two options for 1.: It can be what @tofro in a comment referred to as an imperative to the self (*Let us do this!*). Some call this first-person-plural imperative an [adhortative](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adhortativ). Or it can be a question (*Will/ shall we do it?*). Examples 2. and 3. can only be interpreted as questions (*Can I do also this one?* and *Did I do this?*).

Comment: Is an answer like "Ja, habe ich" would be wrong then? When someone asks for example, have you done your HW?

Comment: No, it would be right, because it is short for _Ja, **das** habe ich_, where the _das_ was simply omitted. The "virtually present" word _das_ is in the first position and _habe_ is in the second position. In your examples, however, the word _das_ is not at the first position, but the verbs are; and this word order is the reason why these sentences are imperatives or questions, respectively.